# How to make a regex to parse optional fragments in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following string with groups u,c,m,p:
u5684c76431m33290p55030352942b366a1ca6b310
i need to parce it by the following way:

```
 Regex regex = new Regex("regex here");
 foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(source))
 switch (match.Groups[1].Value.ToLower())
 {
 case "u":
 // u logic here
 break;
 case "c":
 //c  logic here
 ...
```

with next conditions:

- groups are optional
- all groups except "p" is integer
- "p" is numbers+letters(guid 24 chars length)
- The order of groups could be random

Please, help me to make a regex.

--
update: sometimes the "p" group could be integer.

Comment: I wouldn't bother using regex. Start by pulling out p + 24 chars. That way it wont interfere with finding the other values. Then just use first `IndexOf` each letter to work out substrings

Comment: So, i can simplify my conditions with strong groups order but optional, i think that not a difficult stuff for regex, but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on a regex approach, you can try with this regex:

`(?:(?<class>p)(?<value>[A-Za-z0-9]{24})|(?<class>u|c|m)(?<value>[0-9]+))`

In C# code, it might be something like:

```
 var rx = new Regex(@"(?:(?<class>p)(?<value>[A-Za-z0-9]{24})|(?<class>u|c|m)(?<value>[0-9]+))", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant| RegexOptions.Compiled);
 for (Match m = rx.Match(source); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch())
 { 
     var class = m.Groups["class"].Value;
     var value = m.Groups["value"].Value;
 }
```